# Views value lost on tab change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i am developing a survey application the problem i am facing is that a layout contains a question `TextView` Yes/No `RadioGroup` and a Remarks `EditText` field.
So i create a layout containing these things and include in my `fragment` for 5-10 time depending on number of questions. Question is set dynamically through code.
Its a tabbed activity containing 4-5 tabs/fragements, now after selecting required option and entering remarks i moved to next tab but when i returned back to same tab, the value in last View replicates to all views available on that tab. Tab is changed once user click on next button swapping between tabs is disabled and on next click all the data is saved to model (for submission on final tab) and next tab is active through code `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);`. Although model data is not tempered but view data is lost

**my custom layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgOptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rgYes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="@string/yes" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rgNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="@string/no" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etRemarks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/remarks"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

**fragment xml:**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_odetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"/>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                layout="@layout/observerlayoutcustom1" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                layout="@layout/observerlayoutcustom1" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                layout="@layout/observerlayoutcustom1" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/view4"
                layout="@layout/observerlayoutcustom1" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/view5"
                layout="@layout/observerlayoutcustom1" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/view6"
                layout="@layout/observerlayoutcustom1" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/view7"
                layout="@layout/observerlayoutcustom1" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/view8"
                layout="@layout/observerlayoutcustom1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

setOffScreenPageLimit method of viewpager may solve this problem.
set viewpager’s offScreenpagelimit to 4